# How do I say "Outdoor Pre-show"

Tags: перевод, лексикон

"Show" stands for "шоу" but I'm failing to find a precise term for "pre-show", should it be just "пре-шоу" or what?

Comment: thank you for your effort for making the question on-topic and welcome to the Russian SE!

Comment: @shabunc Hi shabunc, My apologies for not reading the rules correctly. Glad that you could help!

Comment: basically Russian doesn't have a standard equivalent, despite the fact that such an event was  commonplace before movie screening in cinemas, you'll need to opt for a suggestion you like the most

Comment: @shabunc why did you delete my comment? what rule did you follow doing that?

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка it's not relevant since the question is re-opened

Comment: @shabunc what isn't relevant? my comment or my questions? as far as comment relevance is concerned i will appreciate if you leave it to me to delete it when it loses relevance OK? you're not a censor, you're a moderator and tacit deletion of comments unbeknownst to their authors is overstepping your duty, besides being simply tacky, you understand that?... so what rule did you follow?

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка it's not censorship, it's that you comment was literally "open this question", question was opened after reediting, hence the comment became irrelevant - that happens quite often and if you have concerns about that practice - feel free to raise your voice. Not here however. Comments are supposed to have something to do with the post.

Comment: @shabunc you could signal to me that it's open which would make me understand that the comment is redundant, are you too cool to do that? have some decency... i won't raise any concerns over what you're not supposed to do in the first place

Comment: @KitSithinun, knowing what kind of show and pre-show is expected (context) could help getting perfect match

Comment: @Sanctus Hi ST, thanks for da reply. A main musical show will have a small dance performance outside the theatre. so Im trying to call this thingy

Comment: @KitSithinun, then I think it would be @Баян's answer. `разогрев` more suitable for music concerts, like rock and metal stuff. Musical show + dance goes well with `предваряющее выступление` IMHO

Comment: `предваряющее выступление снаружи`, if you wanna stress location and it is not clear from other materials.

Answer (score 7):

You can also use `разогрев` for something that happens before the main element of the show.

Answer (score 2):

Пре-шоу, Предшоу or Развлекательная программа. Pre-show goes at a time when the audience takes places.

Also, Pre-show it is as like a trailer (трейлер, анонс) before watch a movie in cinema.

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of awkward but for the lack (if any) of a better term

**предварительное выступление

предварительный концерт

предваряющее выступление

предваряющий концерт**

can be used

Answer (score 0):

«Прешоу» would be understood by most young Russians, but the translation that Multitran gives is much wordier:

> наружная предварительная развлекательная программа